# canvas with mouse that moves ball

Tags: javascript, html, animation, canvas

I have a mouse image and a cheese image with line in-between.  Works fine. Does nothing except look good.

I added a ball that follows the user mouse and it cleared all my images.  I tried to add layers(I am a total newbie).

I want the mouse user to be able to lead just the ball on top of  the mouse image to the cheese.  After I get that working, I will have the cheese turn into a separate image.

The mouse user can lead the ball anywhere.  It does not have to just be on the line in-between the two images.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<title>Mouse Event</title>

<style>

    canvas {
        border: #333 10px solid;
    }

</style>
```

```
<div style = "position: relative;">
    <canvas id = "layer1" width="600px" height="600px"
     style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; z-index: 0;></canvas>
    <canvas id = "layer2" width="600px" height="600px"
     style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; z-index: 1;></canvas>


<script>

    var canvas1 = document.querySelector("#layer1");
    var context = canvas1.getContext("2d");

    //Get the mouse position
    //First, listen for the mouse event & call setMousePosition
    //This function assigns the current horizontal and vertical mouse
    //position to the mouseX,Y properties, it relies on the clientX
    //and Y properties that the MouseEvent-based event arument object provides
    var canvasPos = getPosition(canvas);

    var mouseX = 500;
    var mouseY = 500;

    canvas1.addEventListener("mousemove", setMousePosition, false);

    function setMousePosition(e) {
      mouseX = e.clientX - canvasPos.x;//now stores the position returned by the getPosition function
      mouseY = e.clientY - canvasPos.y;
    }       

    function update() {
      context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);//clears earlier positions
      context.beginPath();
      context.arc(mouseX, mouseY, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true);
      context.fillStyle = "LightSeaGreen";
        context.lineWidth = 5;
        context.strokeStyle = "yellow";
        context.fill();
        context.stroke();

      requestAnimationFrame(update);
    }
    //Get the Exact Mouse Position
    function getPosition(el) {
      var xPosition = 0;
      var yPosition = 0;

      while (el) {
        xPosition += (el.offsetLeft - el.scrollLeft + el.clientLeft);
        yPosition += (el.offsetTop - el.scrollTop + el.clientTop);
        el = el.offsetParent;
      }
      return {
        x: xPosition,
        y: yPosition
      };
    }       

    update();

    var canvas2 = document.querySelector("#layer2");
    var context = canvas2.getContext("2d");

    //draw connecting line
    context.moveTo(30,30);
    context.bezierCurveTo(-50,600, 500, 0, 300,500);
    context.lineWidth = 15;
    context.strokeStyle = "teal";
    context.stroke();

    context.fillStyle = "#ff6600";
    context.font = "bold 35px 'Book Antiqua'";
    context.fillText("Help Me", 300,100);
    context.fillText("find the cheese,", 300, 135);
    context.fillText("Please!", 300, 170);


    //load cheeseImage
    var cheeseImage = new Image();
    cheeseImage.src = "images/transparentCheese.png";
    cheeseImage.addEventListener("load", loadImage, false);

    //load mouse image
    var mouseImage = new Image();
    mouseImage.src = "images/mouse.png";
    mouseImage.addEventListener("load", loadImage, false);


    function loadImage(e) {
        context.drawImage(cheeseImage,10,10);
        context.drawImage(mouseImage,210,400);

    }


</script>

</div>
```

[mouse[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUXZ7.png)[cheese](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8mI2O.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The images are gone because the update function clears the canvas each frame of the animation (context.clearRect), but you want the canvas to clear so don't delete that.

You need to put all the code to draw the things you would like on the canvas inside the update function, or functions the update code calls.

Also its best to wait until both images have loaded before calling the update() function for the first time.

I have modified your code and added some comments, hopefully it makes sense...

```
function update() {
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);//clears earlier positions
  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(mouseX, mouseY, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true);
  context.fillStyle = "LightSeaGreen";
    context.lineWidth = 5;
    context.strokeStyle = "yellow";
    context.fill();
    context.stroke();

    // Call functions to draw text and images on the canvas.
    drawText();
    drawCheese();
    drawMouse();

  requestAnimationFrame(update);
}
//Get the Exact Mouse Position
function getPosition(el) {
  var xPosition = 0;
  var yPosition = 0;

  while (el) {
    xPosition += (el.offsetLeft - el.scrollLeft + el.clientLeft);
    yPosition += (el.offsetTop - el.scrollTop + el.clientTop);
    el = el.offsetParent;
  }
  return {
    x: xPosition,
    y: yPosition
  };
}       

var canvas2 = document.querySelector("#layer2");
var context = canvas2.getContext("2d");


function drawText() {
    //draw connecting line
  context.moveTo(30,30);
  context.bezierCurveTo(-50,600, 500, 0, 300,500);
  context.lineWidth = 15;
  context.strokeStyle = "teal";
  context.stroke();

  context.fillStyle = "#ff6600";
  context.font = "bold 35px 'Book Antiqua'";
  context.fillText("Help Me", 300,100);
  context.fillText("find the cheese,", 300, 135);
  context.fillText("Please!", 300, 170);
}

// Draw cheese image on canvas
function drawCheese() {
    context.drawImage(cheeseImage,10,10);
}

// Draw mouse image on canvas.
function drawMouse() {
    context.drawImage(mouseImage,210,400);
}


//load cheeseImage
var cheeseImage = new Image();
cheeseImage.src = "images/transparentCheese.png";
cheeseImage.addEventListener("load", loadImage, false);

//load mouse image
var mouseImage = new Image();
mouseImage.src = "images/mouse.png";
mouseImage.addEventListener("load", loadImage, false);


var imagesLoaded = 0;

// Called when image is loaded.
function loadImage(e) {
        // Increment the number of images loaded
        imagesLoaded += 1;

        // If both images have loaded call the update function for the first time.
        if (imagesLoaded == 2) {
            update();
        }
}
```